# Why does this variable change value despite not being referenced?

Tags: python, pygame

I need to create a base rectangle, and the blitted rectangle (default_rect and rect) for both scaling and scrolling purposes. I'm trying to change the y value of the RECT individually, but it somehow changes the value of default_rect also? I have no idea why. Perhaps the issue is coming from somewhere else. I have tried to create a minimum reproducible example to show what I'm talking about.

```
class Element(pg.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, img, x, y, placement="center"):
    super().__init__()
    self.image = img
    if placement == "topright":
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topright=(x, y))
    if placement == "center":
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
    self.default_rect = self.rect
    print("Test")

def update_rect(self, y_offset):
    self.rect.centery = self.default_rect.centery + y_offset
```

When calling this update_rect() function, I see no reason why the value of self.default_rect.centery should be affected at all. This is the only place I reference default_rect.centery. I do not think that the issue is coming from the `__init__` running multiple times because "Test" is only printed when initalising.

Rest of the minimum reproducible example. The rectangle continuously increases it's y position to -1,000,000 in seconds (without fps limit).

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()

screen_width, screen_height = 800, 600
screen = pg.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

grey = (150, 150, 150)
dark_grey = (60, 60, 60)


class Element(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, img, x, y, placement="center"):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = img
        if placement == "topright":
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topright=(x, y))
        if placement == "center":
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        self.default_rect = self.rect
        print("Test")

    def update_rect(self, y_offset):
        self.rect.centery = self.default_rect.centery + y_offset


class ScrollBar(Element):
    def __init__(self, x, y, total_bar_w, total_bar_h, total_h):
        img = pg.Surface((total_bar_w, total_bar_h))
        img.fill(dark_grey)
        super().__init__(img, x, y, "topright")

        bar_w = 0.98*total_bar_w
        bar_h = (total_bar_h / total_h) * total_bar_h
        bar_img = pg.Surface((bar_w, bar_h))
        bar_img.fill(grey)
        self.bar = Element(bar_img, x, y, "topright")

        self.total_h = total_h
        self.ratio = self.total_h / self.rect.h
        self.offset = 0
        self.y_offset = 0

        self.pressed = False
        self.active = False

    def update(self):
        pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0]

        # Check if the slider bar was pressed
        if click and self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            self.active = True
        # Checking if mouse was released or mouse left the allowed zone
        if not click or abs(pos[0] - self.rect.midleft[0]) > self.rect.w*3:
            self.active = False

        if self.active:
            self.bar.rect.centery = pos[1]
            if self.bar.rect.top < 0:
                self.bar.rect.top = 0
            if self.bar.rect.bottom > self.rect.top + self.rect.h:
                self.bar.rect.bottom = self.rect.top + self.rect.h

            # Calculate y offset for elements. Multiply by negative
            # to allow us to add the offset rather than subtract
            self.y_offset = (self.bar.rect.centery - self.bar.rect.h / 2) * -self.ratio

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
        screen.blit(self.bar.image, (self.bar.rect.x, self.bar.rect.y))


class Button(Element):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        super().__init__(pg.Surface((w, h)), x, y, "center")
        self.clicked = False

    def update(self):
        self.update_rect(scroll_bar.y_offset)
        action = False
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pg.mouse.get_pos()):
            if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and not self.clicked:
                self.clicked = True
                action = True
            if not pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                self.clicked = False
        return action

    def draw(self):
        pg.draw.rect(screen, "blue", self.rect)


button1 = Button(400, 100, 200, 150)
button2 = Button(400, 300, 200, 150)
button3 = Button(400, 500, 200, 150)
buttons = [button1, button2, button3]

total_height = screen_height * 2
scroll_bar = ScrollBar(screen_width, 0, 0.05 * screen_width, screen_height, total_height)


run = True
while run:
    screen.fill("white")

    for button in buttons:
        button.draw()
        if button.update():
            print("Button's y value is: " + str(button.rect.y))

    scroll_bar.update()
    scroll_bar.draw()

    for e in pg.event.get():
        if e.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False
        if e.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                print(f"{button1.rect.y} / {button2.rect.y} / {button3.rect.y}")
            if e.key == pg.K_r:
                print(scroll_bar.y_offset)

    pg.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `self.default_rect = self.rect` in `__init__()` both variables are references to the same object. So later in `update_rect()` when you change `self.rect.centery`, the change is reflected in `self.default_rect` because they both refer to the same object.

To understand how this works, check out the excelent talk by Ned Batchelder about [names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! Now that I phrase it differently as "assigning an object to a variable" it makes a lot of sense that they should refer to the same object, but in my mind it sounded much more like I was creating a separate object with the same properties. Solved!

Edit: In the talk by Ned Batchelder, he states: "If two names refer to the same value, this doesn’t magically link the two names. Reassigning one of them won’t reassign the other also." How come it seems that the rect is bound to default_rect?

Comment: He seems to state that the 2 names aren't linked, but goes on to explain that changing the original value will also change the other alias because there is only one value? Why does this happen sometimes but not other times?

Comment: Both of the names are 'signposts' labelling the same object at the same location in memory.  If the object is mutable, and you modify it (for example, its a list, and you change a value inside the list), then both names will still reference the now modified list.  But, if the object at the location is immutable (numbers, str, bool, tuples, frozen sets, frozen Dataclasses, and a few other options), then the object cannot be modified, and setting the name to a new value will instead point it at a new immutable object at a different memory location, without changing the other name/'signpost.'

Comment: @AuraZz These are two different situations. What the quote is referring to is if you do `self.rect = ...` this assignment won't have any effect on `self.default_rect`. Notice how this is different from `self.rect.centery = ...`. In the later case you are changing something about the object which `self.rect` refers to. In the former, you are changing `self.rect` to refer to a different object.

Comment: @AuraZz In other words, changing `self.rect` to refer to a different value doesn't change `self.default_rect`. On the other hand, changing a property of the value which `self.rect` refers to will be seen in `self.default_rect` because it refers to the same value and can see any changes to it.